# Godot - get_configuration_warning no work in CollisionShape2D

Tags: godot, gdscript

When I create a node CollisionShape2D the method : _get_configuration_warning()  no work. for anothers types of node work nice.

I already put the keyword 'tool' at top, and incluse I put a update_configuration_warning in the _ready function. I save, return, open again. Nothing. And the docs is not clear about it.

What I need to do for this work?

Example of code :

```
# the scene is only this node
tool
extends CollisionShape2D

func _get_configuration_warning() -> String : 
    return "Custom warning" # no work

func _ready() -> void : 
    update_configuration_warning() # maybe unnecesary
```

Comment: Your code works for me (Godot v 3.4.2).